# Determine if set is linearly independent in folowing vector space

Tags: linear-algebra, vector-spaces

$\{sin x,cos^2 x, cos 2x\} $ in  $\mathbb  R^\mathbb R $ over $ \mathbb R$

If i understand linear independence correctly, set is not lin. independent, because $cos 2x$ can be expressed by $cos^2 x-sin^2 x$, despite this I'm not sure if its enough to say that set is linearly dependent.

Comment: Well, in fact $\;\cos2x=\cos^2x-\sin^2x\;$ , so the set still has a chance to be independent

Comment: Isn't one of linear independence condition that none of vectors can be expressed as linear combination of remaining vectors?

Comment: Try supposing that there is a linear dependence: $a \sin x + b \cos^2 x + c \cos 2x = 0$.  Then evaluate at various values of $x$, to get relations on the coefficients.  What do you find?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Though I assume you just made a notational mistake, it is not true that $\cos 2x = \cos^2 x - \sin x$. The correct formula is  $\cos 2x=\cos^2 x−\sin^2 x$. Nevertheless, this formula will not help you since you consider $\mathbb{R}^{\mathbb{R}}$ to be a *real vector space*, meaning that you cannot multiply the elements of the space. You cannot multiply two vectors in a given vector space until you define some other structure which makes it more then a vector space. Thus, since $\cos 2x $ cannot be expressed using a finite *linear* combination of $\cos^2 x$ and $\sin x$, the set is linearly independent.

Comment: Your answer does not contain a proof of linear independence.

Comment: Indeed, I have not provided the computation proving that $\cos 2x $ cannot be expressed usinng $\cos^2 x $ and $\sin x$ which was done in @DonAntonio's answer. Yet it seemed to me that the OP's problem with understanding the linear dependence/independence was rather due to confusion about the possible coefficients that can be used in the linear combination, specifically that we can use the coefficients from $\mathbb{R}$ only.

Answer (score 2):

Suppose there are three scalars $\;a,b,c\in\Bbb R\;$ s.t.

$$a\sin x+b\cos^2x+c\cos2x=0\implies\begin{cases}a-c=0\;,\;\;&x=\frac\pi2\\{}\\
b+c=0\,,\;\;&x=\pi\\{}\\
-a-c=0,
,&x=-\frac\pi2\end{cases}$$

solving the above linear system we get $\;'a=b=c=0\;$ and thus the set is lin. ind.